# Can selenium open remote headless chrome's debugging page?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

> - Platform:
>
>   - Computer A (Grid's Hub): Ubuntu 14.04
>   - Computer B (Grid's Node): Ubuntu 16.04
> - python + Selenium Grid + headless Chrome

#### what i did

I'm using Selenium Grid - having set a Hub in Computer A and a Node in Computer B. And I'm able to open Computer B's headless Chrome by python codes below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

def open_remote_headless_chrome():
    # parameters
    head_port = 9222

    # config options
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable'
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    # options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=' + str(head_port))
    # -> If I uncomment the line above, it will cause error

    # open remote headless Chrome
    driver = webdriver.Remote(
        desired_capabilities=options.to_capabilities()
    )

    # bing 'headless'
    driver.get("http://www.sogou.com")
    elem_search_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='query']")
    elem_search_input.send_keys("headless")
    elem_search_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    # To Ensure that I've successfully opened the headless Chrome
    time.sleep(1)  # wait till search result page loaded
    print(driver.title)  # was the right title - "headless - 搜狗搜索"

    driver.quit()
```

But when I add `--remote-debugging-port=9222` to `options` ,the process running in terminal will freeze and throw errors finally.

> (I will post terminal info here later today...)

#### what i found

`netstat -a | grep localhost | grep ESTABLISHED` on Computer B listed the following infomation:

```
tcp        0      0 localhost:36976         localhost:socks         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:46056         localhost:12970         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:55144         123.126.51.32:https     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:55918         localhost:24800         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:36978         localhost:socks         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:35700         localhost:socks         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:12970         localhost:46056         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:46068         localhost:12970         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:12970         localhost:45556         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:45554         localhost:12970         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:45556         localhost:12970         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:12970         localhost:46068         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:36974         localhost:socks         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:12970         localhost:45554         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:34520         localhost:19080         ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 localhost:50004         localhost:4444          ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 localhost:59614         122.97.254.22:http      ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 localhost:5555          localhost:43993         ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 localhost:19080         localhost:34520         ESTABLISHED
udp
```

> My trying proved that the related port on Computer B always starts with `12`, like 12500, 12341, 12970...

When I visit `localhost:12970` on Computer B, I thought I've found the debugging page I've been seeking so far, but it's in fact different from a normal one:

```
<!-- body of site localhost:12970 -->
<div id="caption">Inspectable WebContents</div>
<div id="items">
    <p>
        <div title="The tab already has active debugging session">
            <div>headless - 搜狗搜索</div>
        </div>
    </p>
</div>
```

While a 'normal' one is like:

```
<!-- start normally in command line by `chrome --headless --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=9222 http://www.sogou.com/` -->
<div id="caption">Inspectable WebContents</div>
<div id="items">
    <p>
        <a href="https://chrome-devtools-frontend.appspot.com/serve_file/@3cf8514bb1239453fd15ff1f7efee389ac9df8ba/inspector.html?ws=localhost:9222/devtools/page/289a78c9-d480-4c90-9469-c69e2d8133a4&remoteFrontend=true" title="搜狗搜索引擎 - 上网从搜狗开始">
            <div>搜狗搜索引擎 - 上网从搜狗开始</div>
        </a>
        <!-- Note that the div tag wrapped in an anchor! -->
    </p>
</div>
```

#### what i want

Am I able to **add a debug port** to options ? And if able, am I able to open a `Remote()` FireFox(since one can not open debug link still in Chrome) to **access the debug page remotely** (in my case, whose url is `localhost:9222`), which is for debugging headless Chrome.

#### thx

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to debug your website or some chrome extension using this?

Comment: @TarunLalwani What I am trying to do is testing some webpage remotely through headless chrome - in this way the remote user will not be aware. And when some specific conditions happen(, like when the test encounter a captcha,) I would like to open debug page remotely to transfer control to my remote user.

Comment: That is not possible. Because when you control the browser using Selenium, it is already using the debugger connection. There can only be one connection to debugger. So you can open the page remotely but won't allow to debug the site. Try to see if this can be done manually first and then look at automation. My initial analysis doing it manually shows that the page cannot be debugged remotely when Chromedriver is already attached as a debugger to the chrome

Comment: You may be looking for https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_chrome/selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_cdp_cmd

Comment: or https://github.com/fate0/pychrome